# how to send a zip file from server to client+meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have the following code at server side to download a zip(destpath),zip file is getting downloaded at the client but when we try to open it shows invaild zip content.

```
this.route('download', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/download/:_id',
    action: function() {
        destPath="/home/rootuser/botbuilder/botBuilderdevelo/Python.zip"
        if (fs.existsSync(destPath)) {
            filetext = fs.readFileSync(destPath, "utf-8");//tried encoding binary
        }

        var headers = {
            'Content-Type':  'application/octet-stream',//tried application/zip
            'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + "pyth" + '.zip'
        };
        this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
        return this.response.end(filetext);
        // i tried this.response.end(destpath);
    }   
})
```

Comment: What router are you using?

Comment: using iron router

Comment: Do you know how to use MD5 hashes to verify the file content for downloads? If so, check if the MD5 is correct. If yes, there is definitely a problem at the download. If not, maybe it got already corrupted at the upload.

Comment: You should definitely use `binary` while reading file. Also, try this code with something that you could compare, some text file, for example.

Comment: text file are downloading,i used binary while reading file for zip but doesnt worked :(

Answer (score 0):

specify the encoding when calling res.end() solved the problem:

```
this.response.end(filetext1,"binary");
```

Comment: what you did in client end to download the send folder?